# Upload pdf to wrong folder using OOP PHP Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I have created a products table where the pdf's are located (location). Also, I have a folder(store) in the main root where all pdf's are located. Then, I have created a directory to this store (STORE_DIR) and an upload class, but when I update a product through the Admin Panel, the pdf appears in a wrong folder (media/catalogue). Therefore, it is not updated in the location field, neither in store folder. I would really appreciate any help because it is really important for this project to allow the Admin uploading the pdf's.

This is my products table:

```
     CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products` (
     `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     `date` datetime NOT NULL,
     `category` int(11) NOT NULL,
     `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
     `image` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
     `description` text NOT NULL,
     `author` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
     `price` decimal(5,2) NOT NULL,
     `location` text NOT NULL,
     `expiry` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
     `extra` text NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
     ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=31 ;
```

This is the config.php where I have the directories and paths

```
    <?php
    if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
    session_start();
    }

   //site domain name with http
   defined("SITE_URL")
    || define("SITE_URL", "http://" .$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);

   //directory separator
   defined("DS")
    || define("DS", DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR); 

    //root path
    defined("ROOT_PATH")
    || define("ROOT_PATH", realpath(dirname(__FILE__).DS."..".DS)); 

    //classes folder
    defined("CLASSES_DIR")
    || define("CLASSES_DIR", "classes");

    //pages directory
   defined("PAGES_DIR")
    || define("PAGES_DIR", "pages"); 

    //modules folder
    defined("MOD_DIR")
    || define("MOD_DIR", "mod"); 

   //includes folder
  defined("INCLUDES_DIR")
    || define("INCLUDES_DIR", "includes"); 

   //frontend folder
   defined("FRONTEND_DIR")
    || define("FRONTEND_DIR", "frontend");

   //emails path
   defined("EMAILS_PATH")
    || define("EMAILS_PATH", ROOT_PATH.DS ."emails");

   //store path
  defined("STORE_DIR")
    || define("STORE_DIR", "store");

   //catalogue images path
  defined("CATALOGUE_PATH")
    || define("CATALOGUE_PATH", ROOT_PATH.DS."media".DS."catalogue"); 

   //add all the above directories to the include path
  set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR,array(
    realpath(ROOT_PATH.DS.CLASSES_DIR),
    realpath(ROOT_PATH.DS.PAGES_DIR),
    realpath(ROOT_PATH.DS.MOD_DIR),
    realpath(ROOT_PATH.DS.INCLUDES_DIR),
    realpath(ROOT_PATH.DS.FRONTEND_DIR),
    realpath(ROOT_PATH.DS.STORE_DIR),
    get_include_path()
)));    
 ?>
```

This is the upload function. I need to mention that image files are uploaded correctly, the problem is the pdf.

```
      public function upload($path = null) {

    if (!empty($path) && is_dir($path) && !empty($this->_files)) {

        foreach($this->_files as $key => $value) {

            $name = helper::cleanString($value['name']);

            if ($this->_overwrite == false && is_file($path.DS.$name)) {
                $prefix = date('YmdHis', time());
                $name = $prefix."-".$name;
            }

            if (!move_uploaded_file($value['tmp_name'], $path.DS.$name)) {
                $this->_errors[] = $key;
            }
            if ($this->_overwrite == false && is_file($name)) {
                $prefix = date('YmdHis', time());
                $name = $prefix."-".$name;
            }

            if (!move_uploaded_file($value['tmp_name'], $name)) {
                $this->_errors[] = $key;
            }

            $this->_names[] = $name;

        }

        return empty($this->_errors) ? true : false;

    }
    return false;

}
```

Finally, this is the edit page in the Admin Panel:

```
       <?php 
       $id = url::getParam('id');

        if (!empty($id)) {

        $objCatalogue = new catalogue();
        $product = $objCatalogue->getProduct($id);

       if (!empty($product)) {

       $objForm = new form();
      $objValid = new validation($objForm);
    $categories = $objCatalogue->getCategories();
     if ($objForm->isPost('name')) {

        $objValid->_expected = array(
            'category',
            'name',
            'author',
            'description',
            'price',
             'ebook'
        );

        $objValid->_required = array(
            'category',
            'name',
            'author',
            'description',
            'price',
             'ebook'
        );

        if ($objValid->isValid()) {

            if ($objCatalogue->updateProduct($objValid->_post, $id)) {

                $objUpload = new upload();

                if ($objUpload->upload(CATALOGUE_PATH)) {

                    if (is_file(CATALOGUE_PATH.DS.$product['image'])) {
                        unlink(CATALOGUE_PATH.DS.$product['image']);

                    }

                    $objCatalogue->updateProduct(array('image' =>   $objUpload->_names[0]), $id);

                          helper::redirect('../admin'.url::getCurrentUrl(array('action', 'id')).'&action=edited');
                } else {
                     helper::redirect('../admin'.url::getCurrentUrl(array('action', 'id')).'&action=edited-no-upload');
                }
                    if ($objUpload->upload(STORE_DIR)) {

                    if (is_file(STORE_DIR.$product['location'])) {
                        unlink(STORE_DIR.$product['location']);

                    }

                    $objCatalogue->updateProduct(array('location' =>  $objUpload->_names[0]), $id);

                     helper::redirect('../admin'.url::getCurrentUrl(array('action', 'id')).'&action=edited');
                } else {
                    helper::redirect('../admin'.url::getCurrentUrl(array('action', 'id')).'&action=edited-no-upload');
                }

            } else {
                 helper::redirect('../admin'.url::getCurrentUrl(array('action', 'id')).'&action=edited-failed');
            }

        }

    }

    require_once('frontend/_header.php'); 
    ?>
   <div class="col-md-9 col-lg-10 main">
    <h1>Edit Product</h1>
   </div>
   <div class="container">
   <div class="row"> 
    <div class="col-md-6">  
     <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="category">Category</label>
          <?php echo $objValid->validate('category'); ?>
            <select name="category" id="category" class="form-control">
                <option value="">Select one&hellip;</option>
                <?php if (!empty($categories)) { ?>
                    <?php foreach($categories as $cat) { ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $cat['id']; ?>"
                    <?php echo $objForm->stickySelect('category',  $cat['id'], $product['category']); ?>>
                     <?php echo helper::encodeHtml($cat['name']); ?>
                    </option>
                    <?php } ?>
                 <?php } ?>
            </select>
      </div>
       <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
          <?php echo $objValid->validate('name'); ?>
              <input type="text" name="name" id="name" 
                value="<?php echo $objForm->stickyText('name', $product['name']); ?>" class="form-control" />
      </div>
       <div class="form-group">
               <label for="author">Author</label>
               <?php echo $objValid->validate('name'); ?>
               <input type="text" class="form-control" id="author" name="author" value="<?php echo $objForm->stickyText('author', $product['author']); ?>">
          </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="description">Description</label>
         <?php echo $objValid->validate('description'); ?>
            <textarea name="description" id="description" cols="" rows=""
                class="form-control"><?php echo $objForm->stickyText('description', $product['description']); ?></textarea>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
        <label for="price">Price</label>
        <?php echo $objValid->validate('price'); ?>
             <input type="text" name="price" id="price" 
                value="<?php echo $objForm->stickyText('price',   $product['price']); ?>" class="form-control" />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="ebook">Ebook (PDF)</label>
        <?php echo $objValid->validate('ebook'); ?>
            <input type="file" name="ebook" id="ebook" size="30"  class="form-control"/>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="image">Image</label>
        <?php echo $objValid->validate('image'); ?>
            <input type="file" name="image" id="image" size="30" class="form-control"/>
      </div>
     <div class="text-center">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-template-main">Update</button>
      </div>
     </form>
     </div>
    </div>
    </div>







    <?php require_once('frontend/_footer.php');
    }
    }
   ?>
```

Thank you in advanced!!

Comment: You told it to go into `$objUpload->upload(CATALOGUE_PATH)` and that is defined as `define("CATALOGUE_PATH", ROOT_PATH.DS."media".DS."catalogue"); `

Comment: So try using `$objUpload->upload(STORE_DIR)`

Comment: Did that do any good?

Comment: It is already in the code  ` if ($objUpload->upload(STORE_DIR)) {
     
      if (is_file(STORE_DIR.$product['location'])) {
       unlink(STORE_DIR.$product['location']);
       
      }`but it is not working.@ RiggsFolly

Comment: No you pass the `CATALOGUE_PATH` as a parameter to the `->upload` method so thats why it puts the files in that location

Comment: Sorry,@ RiggsFolly I don't understand. According to the code I 'm passing the image to CATALOGUE_PATH and the pdf to STORE_DIR. Could you please show how the code would be?